# gcc/g++ are giving different response to empty main function

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++, return

I am using
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1 
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1

If I make a cpp and c file that contains only

```
int main(const int argc, const char *const argv[])
{

}
```

and compile it with `g++ -Wall test_warnings.cpp` I get no warning.

If I compile it with `gcc -Wall test_warnings.c` I get the warning you would expect:

```
test_warnings.c: In function ‘main’:
test_warnings.c:4:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

The same behavior is exhibited if -Wreturn-type is used instead of -Wall.

Why isn't g++ giving me a warning that the return is missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because C and C++ are different languages.

In C++, reaching the end of `main()` without executing a `return` statement is equivalent to executing `return 0;`.

In C, as of the 1990 ISO standard, falling off the end of `main()` returns an undefined status to the calling environment.

C99 changed this, essentially adopting the C++ rule -- but gcc doesn't implement C99 by default. (Try compiling with `-std=c99`.)

In any case, it can't hurt to add a `return 0;` statement to the end of `main()`.